# Problems with triggers permission

Tags: permissions, environment-variables, permission-denied

I was formatting the `/var` and `/home` partitions to remove encryption, but for that I backed up all of its contents to restore later. But when I started the system after the process, I realized that the `/var` directory had permissions problems.
 
When installing programs via `apt-get` I get the following error:

```
Processing 'triggers' for man-db (2.7.0.2-5) ...
Fopen: Permission denied
```

My structure `/var`

```
Root @ lDebian13: / var # ls -all
Total 64
Drwxr-xr-x 13 root matheus 4096 Dec 7 19:43.
Drwxr-xr-x 23 root root 4096 Dec 1 18:17 ..
Drwx ------ 2 root matheus 4096 Dec 7 18:47 backups
Drwxr-xr-x 14 root matheus 4096 Dec 7 20:31 cache
Drwx ------ 2 root matheus 4096 Dec 7 18:47 games 
Drwxr-xr-x 61 root matheus 4096 Dec 7 18:47 lib
Drwx ------ 2 root matheus 4096 Dec 7 18:47 local
Lrwxrwxrwx 1 root matheus 9 Dec 7 19:43 lock -> / run / lock
Drwxr-xr-x 12 root matheus 4096 Dec 7 20:33 log
Drwx ------ 2 root matheus 16384 Dec 7 19:26 + found
Drwx ------ 2 root matheus 4096 Dec 7 18:47 mail
Drwx ------ 2 root matheus 4096 Dec 7 18:47 opt
Lrwxrwxrwx 1 root matheus 4 Dec 7 19:43 run -> / run
Drwxr-xr-x 7 root matheus 4096 Dec 7 18:47 spool
Drwx ------ 34 root matheus 4096 Dec 7 20:35 tmp
```

How can I solve this problem? I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this one](https://bugs.launchpad.net/nexenta/+bug/335056) have a solution.

Citation:

> Magnus Hedemark (viridari) wrote on 2009-02-27:
>
> I have made progress figuring out the root cause (literally).
>
> /var/cache/man needs to be recursively owned by user "man". Many of the locale subdirs were owned by user "root". If you down a "chown -R man /var/cache/man" this problem goes away.
>
> Each of the successive fopen errors seems to be related to updating manpages for each of the locales (thanks to mib_chrol in ##nexenta for finding the open64 call that triggers this)
>
> This is why running /usr/bin/mandb as root does not trigger errors, but dpkg related tools will (as these seem to update /var/cache/man in the context of the "man" user).

Additionally another citation:

> outsider (siderelay) wrote on 2011-10-17:
>
> I just ran into this bug too, and there's not only /var/cache/man, but also /var and /var/cache need to be chmod'ed to 755

Comment: That's it. Please correct your answer so I can vote.